# Jquery Allow number and text (Uppercase)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help how to make my JS allow text with Uppercase?
My code now just allow numeric.

Here is my code so far :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#status, #accs, #pack_b, #de_no, #de_ser, #n_label, #ac_cord_u').autotab_magic().autotab_filter('numeric');
    });
```

Thanks for kind help. :)

Comment: i think you need check with `autotab_magic()` plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `API docs` from [Autotab](http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab/) use the following code for Uppercase and numbers

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#status, #accs, #pack_b, #de_no, #de_ser, #n_label, #ac_cord_u').autotab_magic().autotab_filter('alphanumeric');
});
```